# error: package net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc does not exist

Tags: android, sql-server

i'm trying to connect to SQL Server Database from android studio
i'm using jtds and already import "jtds-1.3.1.jar" module to android studio

in the import part below line i got error

```
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
```

and the error is:

```
"error: package net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc does not exist"
```

. i don't know what i miss.

```
package com.example.mycar4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;


public class database extends AppCompatActivity {

// Declaring layout button, edit texts
Button login;
EditText username,password;
ProgressBar progressBar;
// End Declaring layout button, edit texts

// Declaring connection variables
Connection con;
String un,pass,db,ip;
String usernam,passwordd;
//End Declaring connection variables


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

    // Getting values from button, texts and progress bar
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // End Getting values from button, texts and progress bar

    // Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password
    ip = "***";
    db = "***";
    un = "***";
    pass = "***";
    // Declaring Server ip, username, database name and password


    // Setting up the function when button login is clicked
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            usernam = username.getText().toString();
            passwordd = password.getText().toString();
            CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();// this is the Asynctask, which is used to process in background to reduce load on app process
            checkLogin.execute("");
        }
    });
    //End Setting up the function when button login is clicked
}

public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()

    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(database.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(isSuccess)
        {
            Toast.makeText(database.this , "Login Successfull" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        if(usernam.trim().equals("")|| passwordd.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please enter Username and Password";
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);        // Connect to database
                if (con == null)
                {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = "select * from login where username= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and password = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"' ";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Login successful";
                        isSuccess=true;
                        con.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql5009.mywindowshosting.com;database=DB_A2C00B_login;user=DB_A2C00B_login_admin;password=login@123";
//            ConnectionURL = 
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.9;database=msss;instance=SQLEXPRESS;Network 
Protocol=NamedPipes" ;


        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    }
    catch (SQLException se)
    {
        Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To connect an Android App with a SQL server, you'll need to set up a web (Http) server in between the two. You can build this web server in any language you're familiar with be it java (J2EE) or php etc.

This web server will be hosted with your SQL server and will take Http requests from the Android app, process it, forward the request as queries to your SQL server and then return it back to your app as REST/JSON (the current format of sending data over the web) or SOAP/XML (the old way of sending data over the web).

App >> Web Server >> Database Server

The web server should be RESTful and the app can interact with it via Http requests via the library Retrofit2.

Here's some resources to get you started;

1. [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) by Square.
2. [Retrofit Github](https://github.com/square/retrofit) repository.
3. [Simple CRUD example with Java RESTful Web Service](https://o7planning.org/en/11207/simple-crud-example-with-java-restful-web-service), a brief tutorial.
4. [RESTful Web Services: A Tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069) [Android + Java Web Services](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio or eclipse you should put the jtds jar file in the correct location
it is in the libs  (library) folder inside app n your project. Once you put it in the libs > right click then add library.

another note you should use 1.2.7 or lower which is much supported

[image: jtds location in project]